# Using AutoMapper to map LINQ Query results to ViewModel Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

First some background..I am using the Telerik MVC Grid to display data. The grid expects an IEnumerable to be passed into their GridModel class which I assume takes care of pages, sorting, filtering, etc.

To avoid circular refrences when passing this data as JSON via ajax I need to map the results from my EF linq querys to View model objects...AutoMapper would be my method of choice for this, but the only solution involving AutoMapper I have come up with hurts perfomance very badly.

I have a repository that returns an IEnumerable of my view model type to my action method that is called by the grid..

```
public IEnumerable<ResultViewModel> Search()
    {
        var person = _context.Persons;

         //this works and is the best performance wise but could be made simpler with automapper
        var result = person.Select(x => new ResultViewModel
                            {
                                FirstName = x.firstName,
                                LastName = x.lastName,
                                ///etc...
                            });

        //THIS IS SLOW but works
        //var result = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Person>, IEnumerable<ResultViewModel>>(person);

        //this does not work and errors at runtime
        //var result = person.Select(x => Mapper.Map<Person, ResultViewModel>(x));

        return result;

    }
```

Any ideas on how to keep my performance while using automapper to make things easier. I am assuming that the slow version using automapper is caused by the `person` collection being enumerated...then being parsed later on by the telerik grid

Comment: What error do you get with `person.Select(x => Mapper.Map<Person, ResultViewModel>(x))`?

Comment: @smartcaveman The error is.: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method ...., and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Comment: This mean the `IQueryable` has not been evaluated.  jfar's answer should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you have an Select ( N + 1 ) issue where each item in the loop is loading related properties and therefore issuing another select query.

There shouldn't be any performance issues using automapper.

Try calling `ToList()` on person ( shouldn't it be people? ) before you do the automapping and breaking the IQueryable chain.

Comment: Tried the ToList() still the same problem...the fast way my request takes around 50ms...the automappper way, it takes 700-850ms

Comment: Turn off lazy loading in your context and try again.

Comment: Turning lazy loading off shaved a couple hundres ms off the response time but also prevented me from returning properties from a related class

Comment: @stephen776 - Then you do have a select N + 1 issue.  Use the .Include function to eager load related entities.